# What is the good gem for email domain verification?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I would like to validate the email domain.

For example,

```rb
hotmail.com # correct
hotmil.com # in this case, I want to suggest hotmail.com
```

Anyone can suggest good gems for email domain verification?

Comment: "gmil.com" is a valid domain though. Somebody could register a "gmil.com" domain and have their email over there. The format would still be correct.

Comment: **What are you trying to achieve**? This screams "XY problem" to me.

Comment: For example, there are third party services dedicated to email address verification, e.g. [NeverBounce](https://neverbounce.com/). Or if you want to really be sure that a person has entered their email correctly, why not follow the tried-and-tested industry standard of *sending a confirmation email*? Or if you're just looking to quickly sanitise a list of emails yourself, e.g. by picking out likely mis-spellings, you could just scan for anything that's *almost, but not quite* `gmail` etc?

Comment: However, note that it's against StackOverflow guidelines for questions that are "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more". If you're looking for a specific gem, then google is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Truemail` gem [Gem](https://github.com/truemail-rb/truemail)

The `Truemail` gem helps you validate emails via regex pattern, presence of DNS records, and real existence of email account on a current email server.